# Access inclusion_tag context variables before included template is rendered

Tags: python, django, django-templates, mezzanine, django-template-filters

In my template, I have an inclusion tag that takes a context and reads from it / updates it. Being an inclusion tag, it also renders a template itself. In the "parent" template (the one calling the inclusion tag), I want to access one of the context variables set in the inclusion tag, but I want to do it prior to where the inclusion tag's template is rendered.

Is it possible to do this (perhaps using `{% with %}`) somehow?

To be specific, I'm using Django Mezzanine and I am modifying [templates/generic/includes/comments.html](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/generic/templates/generic/includes/comments.html) for comments. Notice on [line 10](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/generic/templates/generic/includes/comments.html#L16), the [`comment_thread`](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/generic/templatetags/comment_tags.py#L37) tag is used. This tag loads all the comments for a given object and adds them to the context. The issue is, I want to access those comments earlier in the `comments.html` template, say, on line 3 (e.g, I want to show the number of comments, via `all_comments|length`).

So ideally I want a way to call the `comment_thread` tag early in `comments.html` so it can update the context, but I want to show its output later on in the template.

Hopefully this is clear, let me know if it isn't. I'm not sure if Django is capable of doing what I want, I may need to modify the template tag I guess.  I think I could modify the `comment_thread` tag to only update the context, and then use an {% include %} for the template that `comment_thread` renders currently. Still, I'd prefer not to have to modify Mezzanine itself, so if there is a solution to my problem above, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the comment count, then you can just do this in the `includes/comments.html` template:

`{{ object_for_comments.comments.visible.count }}`

If you want access to other things then you are probably best off just writing a simple template tag that provides what you want. For example:

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def comment_metadata(context, parent):
    comments_queryset = parent.comments.visible()
    # Perform whatever analysis you want on the comments, 
    # and return a variable that will be available in your template context.
```

You may need to duplicate some of the logic that is being performed in the `comment_thread` template tag but depending on what information you require you this could be quite minimal.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use the assignment_tag because I want some of the more complex logic (e.g, getting all comments for staff users but only visible comments for other users).